# Algorithm to Compute Greatest Common Divisors in PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

In a PID, given two elements $a,b$ we can define their greatest common divisor, $d$, as the generator of the principal ideal $$(a,b) = (d)$$ Is there an algorithm to compute this GCD or would this mean we instead have a Euclidean Domain?

Comment: If all the information you have on the ring is that it is principal, this means that the only special thing that an algorithm could use is a magic black box that gives a generator for any ideal. But then that is exactly what you are trying to compute.